# How to create a polygon using svg?

Tags: svg, polygon

I want to create a polygon like in the picture below.

I came across the following polygon but I'm not sure how to make it like in the picture.

```css
html,
body,
svg {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon fill="white" points="0,100 200,0 300,100"/>
</svg>
```

But the problem is, I want to top line run parallel to the bottom line. i.e

Also please explain how does the points work like

```
points = 'x1 y1, x1 y2, x3 y3, x3,y4'
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on where you are stuck.  Are you familiar with the cartesian coordinate system (X and Y axes etc).  Or is it just the format of the `points` attribute that you don't understand?

Comment: Use `points = 'x1,y1  x2,y2  x3,y3  x4,y4'`

Comment: @enxaneta propably the point of that notation was that x4 == x3 and x2 == x1

Comment: @AryaStark I've made a working snippet, added black background so that you could see your white polygon

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/points#polygon):

> For `<polygon>`, `points` defines a list of points, each representing a vertex of the shape to be drawn. Each point is define by a X and Y coordinate in the user coordinate system

So, you need `points="x1,y1 x2,y2 x3,y3 x4,y4"` but you have `x2 == x1` and `x4 == x3`, so it's actually `points="x1,y1 x1,y2 x3,y3 x3,y4"`

Your svg also misses `stroke="black"` to draw the black border on your white polygon and `viewBox` could have better coordinates.

Working example below:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon fill="white" stroke="black" points="0,0 0,100 100,150 100,50"/>
</svg>
```